# What is the exact formatting of the Chumash

Tags: sefer-torah, pentateuch-chumash, text, manuscripts

I am looking for the rules for the exact formatting (the visual look) of the Chumash. I thought I was interested in the Torah Scroll, but it turns out that I'm actually looking for info on the Book format.

Questions about formatting.

- Are there page numbers?
- What are these whitespace spans and how large are they and where are they placed / what are they separating?
- How tall is the text (in pixels or inches or millimeters)?
- How many characters can fit on one line / are allowed to be on one line?
- How big is the whitespace between words?
- What font most closely resembles it, is it [ShlomoStam](https://opensiddur.org/help/fonts/)? Or are there better fonts?
- Is there anything but the main Torah text (verse numbers, book titles, etc.)?
- Is the text slanted (italics-like)?
- Is it entirely in black, or are there shades of gray?
- Anything else of interest visually that I missed?

[This](http://www.jtsa.edu/meaning-in-the-torahs-layout) offers some insight. [This](http://thewisdomdaily.com/my-sons-graduation-as-viewed-through-the-mystical-spaces-in-the-torah/) offers none.

I think I am wondering about [Tikkun Soferim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikkun_(book)#Tikkun_soferim), but not sure.

For example, what are these large whitespaces and what are they modelled on?

[image]

Comment: This might be too broad, and contain too many separate questions, to be appropriate for this site.

Comment: It's not that all my subquestions must be answered, I just want to know the general outline of rules for visual formatting.

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but are you seriously asking if a scroll has page numbers?

Comment: @JoshK No I was asking about the book version.

Comment: Updated for it to be about books, which is really what I had in mind.

Comment: The pagination of the book version varies wildly from publisher to publisher. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: There are very little rules for printed Chumash - just like with Christian bibles every publisher can do what he wants

Answer (score 0):

If you're curious to see what all-Hebrew or bilingual Hebrew-English chumashim look like, peruse the sample pages of different chumashim available at websites like [this one](https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/ste.html), which will give you a complete visual of how a page of a serious chumash looks